# detaching the output of a conv layer and modify using numpy libraries and then pass this as an input to next layers in forward pass

Tags: pytorch, detach

```
  self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out =out.detach().numpy()
        out =rand_func(out)
        out =out.from_numpy()
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
```

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Comment: above is the example code  intended to show the method

Comment: When you detach the torch tensor and convert it to numpy the gradient for the backpropagation will not work. See if you can't do the modification on the torch tensor directly instead of using numpy.